# Change is not displayed on page refresh while using IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, knockout.js, internet-explorer-8

I have written some JavaScript functions that will do 2 things when a button is clicked:

1. It will change the label of the button to "Deactivate" from "Activate" and vice versa.
2. The value of the ActiveStatus property will change to 0 from 1 and vice versa.

The code works alright and the change is displayed perfectly in Mozilla Firefox, but whenever I try display the page in IE 8, change is not displayed, although in database, the value changes perfectly.

Here are the JavaScript codes for the button click:

```
$(function () {


    var stat = document.getElementById("stat").value;
    //alert(stat);

    if (stat == 1)
        document.getElementById("butt").value = "Activate";
    else
        document.getElementById("butt").value = "Deactivate";
});




function activeStatus(ActiveStatus) {

    //alert(ActiveStatus);
    if (ActiveStatus == 1) {
        return "Activate";
    }
    else
    return "Deactivate";
}

function change() {

    var butt = document.getElementById("butt").value;

    if (butt == 'Deactivate') {
        document.getElementById("butt").value = "Activate";
        document.getElementById("stat").value = 1;
    }

    else {
        document.getElementById("butt").value = "Deactivate";
        document.getElementById("stat").value = 0;
    }
}
```

Also, an exception message I'm getting whenever I'm trying to view the page in IE 8 is:

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method
```

I'm getting this error at the Country.js JavaScript file. The place where I'm getting this exception is:

```
var url = "/Country/GetAllCountry";
    var refresh = function () {
        $.getJSON(url, {}, function (data) {
            self.Countries(data);
        });
    };
```

More specifically, in this line:

```
self.Countries(data);
```

None of these happen, when I try to run my application in Firefox. All these happen when I try to run my application in IE 8.

Why am I facing this problem????

EDIT-1: I solved my problem partially. The exception:

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method
```

was displayed only because 'Countries' was undefined in Country.js. Countries must be a valid observable, but it has to be declared. I simply had to add this line of code next to it, doing the declaration:

```
self.Countries = ko.observableArray([]);
```

Now the exception has disappeared, still the page is not refreshed after the button click.

Comment: Most likely `self` refers to the current `window` object, and is a protected name in IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this problem is in these 5 simple steps:

1. Select Tools >> Internet Options.
2. Click the Settings button in Browsing History.
3. Select the Every time I visit the webpage radio button.
4. Click OK to close the Settings dialog.
5. Click OK to close the Internet Options dialog.

It works perfectly now.

Courtesy: Gonzalo (https://stackoverflow.com/users/203766/gonzalo)